# W8.1 Restart to repair drive errors... repeatedly

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

This, very frequently, turns up in Action Center.  Various utilities indicate NO problem with any drive attached to the computer.  Google search finds similar issues regarding a LOOP ... but I am not experiencing a (true) 'loop' ... just this false notification.

I have performed

```
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

sfc.exe /scannow
```

both with success ... but no fix.  dism indicated one problem fixed:

> Checking System Update Readiness.
>
> (p)   CSI Payload
>   Corrupt   (Fixed) amd64_prncacla.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_9590ba64d5b91f79\Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB
>
> Summary: Operation: Detect and Repair  Operation result: 0x0 Last
>   Successful Step: Entire operation completes. Total Detected
>   Corruption:   1   CBS Manifest Corruption:    0   CBS Metadata Corruption:    0
>     CSI Manifest Corruption:    0   CSI Metadata Corruption:    0   CSI Payload
>   Corruption:   1 Total Repaired Corruption:    1   CBS Manifest Repaired:  0
>     CSI Manifest Repaired:  0   CSI Payload Repaired:   1   CSI Store Metadata
>   refreshed:    True

Can anyone tell me how to correct this false notification problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If dism is doing a repair then it's not a false detection

Comment: Did "various utilities" include a SMART report on the drive in question? It *could* be that the drive is failing, which might be reported in the "System" event log.

Comment: OK ... so dism repaired something ... but did not fix the problem I am having.  As for the drive failing ... maybe, but the machine is less than a year old.  Utilities used are chkdsk and the W8 disk check utility (same thing, more or less).  The thing about dism is I never heard of it until I read about it in another forum.  Not very sure how to use it ... but will try a SMART report ..  if I can figure out how.  Thank you both for the replies.

Comment: Did not find anything re: SMART and dism .. but I did find "To check your Hard Disk Health natively, open a command prompt window. First type wmic and hit Enter. Then type diskdrive get status and hit Enter." and it said no disk problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is no false report. The file is indeed corrupted and DISM fixed it. I reported this issue some time ago to Microsoft and they could see this corruption inside Microsoft, too. But my contact told me the team dropped the investigation, because they had no idea what causes the corruption.

When you see this error, run DISM to repair the file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the DISM repair DID solve the problem.  I ran it, it fixed 'something', and I exited WMIC but the notification remained. I assumed a 'no fix'.  Since, I have rebooted ... and have not (yet) seen the notification.  I believe I can assume problem solved.

I sincerely want to thank all who have offered help.  Sincerely.